# Scroll to a div, hide/show a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to scroll to a div and show/ hide it using jQuery?

if(scrollVl) < this change scroll to div?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function (){
    var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrollVal > 0){
      $('.something').css("opacity","1");

    }else{
     $('.something').css("opacity","0");
   };
  });
});
```

Comment: is your question can you do that or you have a problem doing that

Comment: i have a problem doing that @@

Comment: you should check the url of jquery if its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.offset()` to get the position of an element relative to the document.

`bottomScrollValue` is the position of document's `scrollTop` in order for `#trigger` to be visible at the bottom of the window.

Remember that `scrollTop` is the length of part of the document that got scrolled up.

In the snippet, I used `$(window).height()` to get the height of the snippet but it will not work properly on native pages. You should use `document.body.clientHeight` for native pages instead.

```js
(function($, window, document) {
  var triggerScroll = $('#trigger').offset().top;
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var bottomScrollValue = $(document).scrollTop() + ($(window).height());
    if (bottomScrollValue >= triggerScroll) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var show = $('#triggerShow');
        show.removeClass('hidden');
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $('#triggerShow').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
  
  $('#filler').on('click', function() {
    var triggerPosition = 0;
 var triggerTop = $('#trigger').offset().top;
 var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // Use document.body.clientHeight for native (non-iFrame) page
 if (triggerTop < windowHeight) {
  triggerPosition = windowHeight - triggerTop + $('#triggerShow').height();
 } else {
  triggerPosition = triggerTop - windowHeight + $('#triggerShow').height();
 }
    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: triggerPosition
    }, 500);
  });
})(window.jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
#filler { height: 1000px; cursor: pointer; }
#triggerShow { transition: opacity .3s; opacity: 1; }
#triggerShow.hidden { opacity: 0; }
#trigger { padding-bottom: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filler">Filler</div>
<div id="triggerShow" class="hidden">to StackOverflow</div>
<div id="trigger">Welcome</div>
```

Comment: thank you for detail explaning, i have tried your solution, but it's not working.

Comment: and then i just copy all your code, its still not working, i used chrome console to debug, it showed 

TypeError  Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

how can i fix this?
thank you!

Comment: @easonchiu That is probably due to conflict between Chrome's native `$`. I have changed `jQuery` to `window.jQuery` in the function invocation. Also updated the part where you click to scroll to an element.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
         
  if(scrollVal > 0){
  $('.something').css("opacity","1");
  
  }else{
   $('.something').css("opacity","0");
  };
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='something' style=''>In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <br/><br/>
  In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
  <br/><br/>
NEW DELHI:  To protest against the government's decision to yank 500-and 1,000-rupee notes, the leaders of 15 different opposition parties will march tomorrow from parliament to the presidential palace of Rashtrapati Bhawan to meet with President Pranab Mukherjee and update him on what they describe as the unrelenting hardship caused to people by the sudden demonetisation move. Prime Minister Narendra Modi met last evening with ministers to review the impact of the sudden demonetisation drive; he reportedly also asked them for an update on how they are promoting digital transactions to steer India away from such a cash-intensive economy.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        // Get scrollbar position to top
        var scrollVal = $(window).scrollTop();

        // Get item position to top
        var itemPosition = $('.something').offset().top;

        // You have passed the item
        if(scrollVal > itemPosition){
            $('.something').css("opacity","1");
        }
        // You are above the item
        else{
            $('.something').css("opacity","0");
        };
    });
});
```